# Ehcache with DB persistence design

Tags: java, database, ehcache

I'm designing an application that has to consume live data from several sources and periodically report on it.  Consumed data will be added to an Ehcache cache and reports will query it.  Once the live data is consumed it needs to be persisted for recovery purposes only.  If the application restarts it will prime the cache with historical data from the DB before connecting to the live data sources (which queue new data).

I'm leaning toward implementing it as a cache-as-sor with JDBC caching: 
1. Receive data from source 
2. Persist to DB 
3. Add to cache 
4. Confirm receipt with source

with 2-4 wrapped in a JTA transaction.

I also looked into Hibernate with Ehcache as a 2nd level cache, but that doesn't seem appropriate.

I'm relatively new to Ehcache so would like some advice on the right design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For persistence, rather than do a "cache-aside", you probably would want to configure your caches to use read-through and some cache writer (either write-through, or write-behind). You can read about these here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/concepts#cache-as-sor
Now I'd avoid JTA, as I fear the overhead might be overkill (except if you really need XA Transaction Recovery) and rather opt for a fault tolerant approach. If you opt for a asynchronous persistence (write-behind), clustering your cache with Terracotta (the WriteBehind Queue would automatically be persistent, recoverable and even HA if multiple nodes are available) is one approach of ensuring every element gets written out to the underlying SoR... All depending on your needs I guess.

Ehcache would let you start with a single node, unclustered approach, simply using read- & write-through caches, that you could grow and fine tune to meet your SLA. As data grows, you'd then be able to move to clustered caches and asynchronous writers (should writes become the issues) or grow your cache sizes (if reads remain the issue). Obviously, you should measure (or at least know what the bottlenecks are you foresee) and choose accordingly. But putting a Cache in front of your RDBMS is a common and well understood pattern to scale read (and write) access to these "slower" stores...

Comment: Cache-aside wasn't a consideration, but cache-as-sor with write-behind a good idea. I completely forgot about the write-behind ability!  Is there a callback when an element is persisted so I can ack receipt to the publisher?  Terracotta and NoSQL solutions are overkill for this project.

Comment: You should be able to do book keeping in your CacheWriter.write(All) methods. Having a decorated cache that would tick the key as "pending" somewhere when a put happens and have the writer clear it when written out successfully I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have data in a cache, the Hibernate looks like overkill. All you need is JDBC, both to implement a cache loader for cache initialization and for saving the data to a database periodically. Or just setup your cache to persist on disk.

Comment: Hibernate only looked favorable because the objects are fairly complex which would make pure JDBC a pain.  Persistance to disk would work, but it's not an option in case we need recover from a host/disk failure.

Comment: I see, but I do not think your solution will work well for often changed data. Just write it to database via JPA/Hibernate , Ehcache may help but I'm sceptic. And do not expect best performance from ORMs.

I'd try to write the data sequentially to a file, then on recovery read last record. 

If you need to be avoid machine failure, you'll have to consider some distributed storage and processing failover.

Answer (score 0):

Then Ehcache + Hibernate is not the solution. What you are describing here is an asynchronous event processing system in which one of the listeners awaits a "event processed successfully" to persist.

NoSQL databases are a far better option in this case, unless you need to strictly rely to a relational database.